# Detect network traffic and execute command

Tags: linux, networking, raspberry-pi

Well, using kind of a dial-up connection, I was wondering if there is any option using Linux (Raspberry Pi as router) to detect incoming traffic on interface wlan0 (and maybe a specific device) so that a command can be executed:

I have two network interfaces on my Pi. One is used for the local WiFi network to be accessed by all my devices, while the traffic is routed to the second interface to the external gateway. That works fine. The issue is that it requires a login from time to time, which is an issue for Alexa devices and bothers me in general. Therefore, I need to execute a script, when a client (of wlan0) wants to use the internet. Any suggestions?

Answer (score 1):

You can use tcpdump, e.g.

```
tcpdump -i wlan0
```

and then spool the output into a script that is looking for a specific pattern.
When it spots the pattern it can then execute a command.

You can specify rudimentary filtering in tcpdump to cut down the output to triggers that might be useful, which will keep the loading fairly low.